# How to exclude one project out of multiple project from one solution during building using MSBuild in command prompt?

Tags: c#, command-prompt, msbuild-4.0

In my project solution has multiple projects and I want to rebuild it using `msbuild` engine but excluding only one project only for that time because I want to build that particular project separately in another method. that's the reason I guess, I can't write Exclude property in

Here is my command -

```
msbuild Demo.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

Is there any way to exclude a project from build at command line?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. please have a look at my ques again I just edit it and also I don't want to change build configuration because its a "SingleImage" and rest of the project in that same solution is "Release"

Comment: Can't you create a new build configuration for msbuild, as per the linked answer? "You can exclude projects at the solution level for a specific build configuration by using the Configuration Manager Dialog in Visual Studio"

Comment: If you don't want to create a custom configuration in the Configuration Manager Dialog, there are a couple of alternatives 1) run the MSBuild command for each `.csproj` file you want to build instead of the `.sln` file 2) Create a separate `.sln` file for this purpose

Comment: @NightOwl888 I liked your both options but it is building dynamically in my case. I will build many solution with this command and every solution has different number of projects so that's the reason I can't build for each project separately and Separate `.sln`  is not possible for this kind of situation. I know this is very weird situation.

Comment: Then use the Configuration Manager Dialog and add a new configuration. This edits the `.sln` file with an additional project configuration. You will also need to go through each `.csproj` to add the appropriate XML conditions and setup accordingly (or at least check them). Once you have a new configuration setup (such as `Release2`) then you can pass `/p:Configuration=Release2` as a parameter and it will compile the solution with your excluded projects.

Comment: @StephenKennedy, My exclude project 's configuration is Single Image and I mentioned `Release` in command.  so, it should not be include in that build process. that's I don't understand. When I build my solution using above command, Unwanted project is also getting build successfully but that I don't want to build because it consumes too much time and I don't wanna waste my time on that unwanted project.